# XPath 2.0 & LibXML2

Tags: php, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, libxml2

I recently came across about **libx** http://www.explain.com.au/libx/ which is supposed to support XPATH 2.0 standard. However the links are all dead. So my question is where can we get the build or is this project completely dead and if it is **are there alternatives**?

Comment: Yea I was also excited to see that project, until I noticed source did not accompany the build.  It's a very possible goal, I don't care what the pessimists say,  but it would definitely require a community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steve Ball bravely started a project to add 2.0 support to libxml early in 2011, but quickly found that it was a bigger project than he had time for, and as far as I can tell, he's made no progress.

Comment: I think the OP's link is his project, and I greatly appreciate his ambition, but without available source nobody can realistically assist.  I also believe with the scope of this work, community collaboration is required, but the extremely permissive licensing dissuades contributions.  Change licence to LGPL, open a GitHub repository, and work can start in a matter of days.  I'd even personally volunteer, if only just to prove this project can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about libxml, but you can use saxon library to get XPATH 2.0 support

Answer (score 1):

XPath 2.0 support is definitely not in libxml2, and won't be any time soon.  Most recent official word I can establish is:

http://www.mail-archive.com/xml@gnome.org/msg04082.html

```
 Sorry, no support for 2.0 planned, the spec change is far too big and
intrusive. Look at the EXSLT extensions which are supported by libxslt
and xsltproc, they are likely to provide the needed extensions.
```

Comment: But that's from 2007. In that time  they could have implemented it half a dozen time...

Comment: @BeniBela, Why do you expect that people will put so much effort in this for free? Clever people will not do this, and obviously any potential XPath 2.0 implementor must be clever.

Comment: I dunno, the people who make Linux, Firefox, Chrome, etc. seem to be fairly clever.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Why not? They look at XPath 2, are awed by its possibilities, and implement it for all their user's benefit.
Too bad then that I'm not very clever and did it. And I don't even have any users :(

Comment: @BeniBela, such an effort requires about 1.5 to 2 years, when all functions from F & O are implemented. In the real world people have to earn their living and cannot stop doing so for two years. So, it is not surprizing that the only free XPath 2.0 completed project I am aware of is PsychoPath: developed by a team of students. So either you are a student or a millionaire who is extremely bored with his unproblematic life and has found a strange hobby :) Whatever the case, I believe that any development of a free XPath 2.0 engine is more an exception that proves the rule -- not the opposite.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev:  No, I don't think it took me more than 4 months of actual programming to implement it (@ 10h/day).  Less, if I had planned to write it standard compatible in the beginning, and were not forced to refactor it 3 times.  

Although they might need to spend a little bit more time, if they want their functions to be as fast as possible and reject invalid inputs, to match the quality of the current libxml. Still, in five years, that would be possible at the weekends only

Comment: @BeniBela, Obviously people have other plans to spend their free time for free. You could contact libxml authors (Daniel Veillard, if I remember well) and suggest they use your implementation. Even before that, find the W3C test suit and run the tests to see if your implementation really qualifies. The 1.5 years estimate is not my own -- if I remember well it was given here or at another forum by one of the implementers of XQSharp (or maybe of BaseX), who have gone through this all. See also the answer by Michael Kay, as another confirmation of this.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Don't you think everyone should write such an implementation in their lives?? My, however, is written in Pascal. Incompatible to everything and useless for everyone... (especially for a php question).  And I have run the tests a long time ago, in fact half of the  time was spend fixing functions which I thought would work, but had missing cases :( (finally got it up to 99.3% for XPath 2, and 97.8% for XQuery 1, excluding test cases that are supposed to raise an error ).

Comment: @BeniBela, Please, contact me at dnovatchev on google's email -- I may know someone, who would be interested in a Pascal implementation. This person is the author of the best in my opinion XSLT 1.0 IDE, and it is written in Delphi.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Hold on hold there was XPATH 2.0 for Delphi?! Since when!?

Comment: @BeniBela Please elaborate :) There is XPATH 2.0 / XQUERY 1.0 for delphi?

Comment: @BeniBela, Re: "Don't you think everyone should write such an implementation in their lives", well, a few years ago I wrote a parser for XPath 2.0 but wasn't interested in writing a full implementation -- most probably, if I have time I'll make it create XQueryX. This is rather mundane work and not sufficiently challenging. Now, when I see that XPath 3.0 can be used as a stand-alone programming language, I would welcome any XPath 3.0 standalone implementation. It certainly must be pluggable into a frontend wrapper that will create the static context and that may communicate with the end user.

Comment: Can you guys start a google project I am interested and I know people who would want to contribute :)

Comment: @RichardO'Reilly, Martin Rowlinson created in Delphi  the XSelerator -- the best XSLT 1.0 IDE ever more than ten years ago -- I am still using the XSelerator almost every day. I think that he may be interested in adding XPath 2.0 features. The XSelerator already can execute external XSLT (and even XQuery processors), such as Saxon 9.1 or Saxon 9.4, or XQSharp, or Altova, ..., etc. Please, send me an email if you want more information.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev There is already an Delphi implementation of LibXML2. IDXML :)

Comment: @RichardO'Reilly, Then simply connect with BeniBela and add XPath 2.0 specific methods to this implementation. The question still remains, though, how many users are currently using this Delphi - based LibXML2 implementation.

Comment: @RichardO'Reilly: My implementation is on sourceforge. Deeply hidden, but it's there. However, it is written for FreePascal, not Delphi. I haven't used Delphi, since Delphi 4, so I don't know if it would run there or how difficult it would be to port. (to Delphi 4 it would be awful, without even having += operators...)